# Need help parsing this object into JSON (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the JSON data (at the bottom) using the `JSON.parse` method in javascript. Below is the code.

```
 var i;
 var myData={};
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $.get("http://localhost:4567/get/233307/loc/15000/10", function(data){
                display(data);

            }, "json");
    });
 function display(x){
    for(i = 0; i <= x.length;i++){
        myData = JSON.parse(x[i]);
    }
    alert(myData[2].uid);
 }
```

The code above, according to me should parse the JSON data and store to `myData`. But the alert that should have given me `233307` gives me an `undefined`. I feel like I'm doing everything right. Any help? Thanks.

```
{"id":64567868968,"uid":233307,"lat":41.418972,"long":-72.8941315,"date":"2010-11-11T16:01:15-05:00"},{"id":64567803255,"uid":
233307,"lat":41.4189505,"long":-72.89411,"date":"2010-11-11T16:00:13-05:00"},{"id":64567803254,"uid":233307,"lat":
41.4189451666667,"long":-72.8940725,"date":"2010-11-11T15:59:11-05:00"},{"id":64567803253,"uid":233307,"lat":
41.4188646666667,"long":-72.8940831666667,"date":"2010-11-11T15:58:08-05:00"},{"id":64567803252,"uid":233307,"lat":
41.4190095,"long":-72.8941905,"date":"2010-11-11T15:57:06-05:00"},{"id":64567700284,"uid":233307,"lat":
41.418972,"long":-72.894169,"date":"2010-11-11T15:56:04-05:00"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Three issues I see:

1. You don't need `JSON.parse()`; by specifying `json` as the `dataType` for the `GET` request, you ask jQuery to automatically parse the response into JSON. So when `display()` gets called, `x` is already a JSON object and not a string that needs to be parsed.
2. You seem to want to iterate over an array in `display()` but the sample response is not an array, it is simply a comma-separated list of JSON objects. It is NOT valid JSON unless it was enclosed in `[]` (making it an array). If that is indeed your response, then jQuery will be unable to parse it and `x` will be undefined.
3. Finally, (once you fix #2), you're already iterating over the array and `myData` gets (re)-assigned with each iteration of the loop to the next JSON object and is finally set to the last JSON object, which is not an array so `myData[2]` is invalid. It should simply be `myData.uid`. Or instead of iterating over the array, since they all have the same `uid`, you might instead change `display()` to:

   ```
    function display(x){
       if(x && x.length > 0){
           alert(myData[0].uid);
       }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing array brackets around your objects

```
[{"id":64567868968,"uid":233307,"lat":41.418972,"long":-72.8941315,"date":"2010-11-11T16:01:15-05:00"},{"id":64567803255,"uid":
233307,"lat":41.4189505,"long":-72.89411,"date":"2010-11-11T16:00:13-05:00"},{"id":64567803254,"uid":233307,"lat":
41.4189451666667,"long":-72.8940725,"date":"2010-11-11T15:59:11-05:00"},{"id":64567803253,"uid":233307,"lat":
41.4188646666667,"long":-72.8940831666667,"date":"2010-11-11T15:58:08-05:00"},{"id":64567803252,"uid":233307,"lat":
41.4190095,"long":-72.8941905,"date":"2010-11-11T15:57:06-05:00"},{"id":64567700284,"uid":233307,"lat":
41.418972,"long":-72.894169,"date":"2010-11-11T15:56:04-05:00"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
function display(x){
    var myData = [];
    for(i = 0; i <= x.length; i++){
        myData.push(JSON.parse(x[i]));
    }
    alert(myData[2].uid);
}
```

? Each iteration of your loop overwrites the previous "myData". I also can't tell what you're trying to do with the `x` variable... It's a JSON object, not an array, and it doesn't contain strings either so you can't evaluate them.